# How can I rewrite this Visual Basic.net loop to make it work?

Tags: vb.net, loops

I have a For Each loop written in Visual Basic that's trying to modify a table it is iterating through. This is causing the ""Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute" exception.

What is frastrating about this is that I've tried to make copies of all the objects that I was using and and only removed from the copy but the exception still happened.

I know that this is due to my using a For Each loop instead of a For or While loop but I could not rewrite my code and make it work (I'm more familiar with C#). This is why I decided to ask for help here.

This is my code. How can I rewrite to be able to remove the Row that I wish to remove? Any help and code would be very appreciated!

```
Dim drAcademicRecord, drSchool As DataRow
For Each drSchool In dsR.Tables("School").Rows
    If drSchool("OrganizationName") = "NA" Then
        For Each drAcademicRecord In dsR.Tables("AcademicRecord").Rows
            If drAcademicRecord("AcademicRecord_Id") = drSchool("AcademicRecord_Id") Then
                dsR.Tables("AcademicRecord").Rows.Remove(drAcademicRecord)  '<-- This is the line causing my exception
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Why do you iterate over multiple tables? Have a look at DataRelations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k21zcyx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at that. I didn't write the original code so I was using what I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use

```
dsR.Tables("AcademicRecord").Rows.Remove(drAcademicRecord)
```

Because you have already got drAcademicRecord, so you can directly delete that row by

```
drAcademicRecord.Delete
```

e.g.

```
For Each drSchool As DataRow In dsR.Tables("School").Select("OrganizationName='NA'")
    For Each drAcademicRecord As DataRow In dsR.Tables("AcademicRecord").Select("AcademicRecord_Id=" & drSchool("AcademicRecord_Id"))
        drAcademicRecord.Delete
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked beutifully and I learned something new. Just out of curiousity, do you know why this code doesn't generate the same exception even though the deletion occurs inside of a loop?
Thanks again!

Comment: After removing the DataTow, the DataTable will re-index itself, therefore if you loop it by using `dsR.Tables("AcademicRecord").Rows(i)` may access the invalid index which has been removed. I would not access the DataRow by using index when I need to add or remove record which may change the table index

Answer (score 3):

```
For i as integer = dsR.Tables("AcademicRecord").Rows.Count - 1 to 0 Step -1
    If dsR.Tables("AcademicRecord").Rows(i)("AcademicRecord_Id") = drSchool("AcademicRecord_Id") Then
        dsR.Tables("AcademicRecord").Rows.RemoveAt(i)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Am I correct to assume that the exception is avoided by essentially going backwards and always having more itenms to iterate through?

Comment: No, the exception is avoided because you don't use an enumerator for traversing the collection. And by going backwards you avoid the need to manually decrement the `i` variable when you delete an item.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I really appreciate your help.